# How to remove spaces and newline in awk for string insertion?

Tags: string, bash, shell, awk, newline

So, I have my apache2 config file like this:

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
             BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" route=node1 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
             BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xx:8009" route=node2 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on  ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
             BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" route=node3 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
             BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xx:8009" route=node4 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
             BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xx:8009" route=node5 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
             BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xx:8009" route=node6 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
             BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" route=node7 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60
            ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
    </Proxy>
```

What I want to do is insert a new BalancerMember with # before the line `ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests`. I will use shell script to do this.

So it should look like:  `#BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" route=node8 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60`

What I have tried is:

```
awk -v s1='"' -v ip="10.0.7.1" -v no="8" '
/ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests/{
print "\n\t\t#BalancerMember " s1 "ajp://" ip ":8009" s1 " route=node" no " loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60"
next
}
1' /tmp/000-site.conf > /tmp/000-site.conf.tmp && mv /tmp/000-site.conf.tmp /tmp/000-site.conf
}
```

So, the above solutions works fine, but leaves newlines, which I don't want. I have tried removing ORS.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "is leaving newlines" but you ARE specifically printing newlines with `print "\n..."` - is that the problem? If not then post the expected output and the output you're actually getting to clarify what the problem is.

Comment: Let me paste the output of my code for better understanding in my question.

Comment: @EdMorton @RavinderSingh13 This was my bad, the code works fine just needed to remove the `\n`. Sorry for wasting your time guys. I feel so stupid now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.(Creating variable `line` of `awk` which will have your new line's value in it)

```
awk -v line='#BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" route=node8 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60' '
/ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests/{
  print "             " line ORS $0
  next
}
1'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code here.

```
awk -v line='#BalancerMember "ajp://10.x.x.xxx:8009" route=node8 loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60' ' ##Creating variable line.
/ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests/{     ##Checking condition here if a line has string ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests then do following.
  print "             " line ORS $0 ##Printing space then variable line ORS and then print currrent line value then.
  next                              ##Mentioning next out of the box keyword to skip all further statements.
}
1                                   ##Mentioning 1 will print the lines here, awk works on condition then action, making condition true here, print action will happen.
'  Input_file                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: I have edited my question code, because I'm using variables.

Comment: @Ashutosh, sorry but I didn't get, please do let me know what is not working?

Comment: @Ashutosh, append `> temp_file  &&  mv temp_file Input_file` to my code where `Input_file` is your actual data file, let me know if that helps?

Comment: @Ashutosh your comments are coming across as extremely rude, entitled, and unappreciative. "change your answer according to my new code with variables.", and "Doesn't work, already tried this." and " Please see the code in the question again. I have already mentioned the same.". Seriously? You might want to consider that Ravinder is trying to help you AND is doing so for free.

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you for your support, Ashutosh- code seems to be working fine as per your question, be clear in your question else.

Comment: I didn't mean that. I am sorry for being rude.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Your code works just fine, but I'm unable to use variables inside the variable `line`. Here is what I have tried: `awk -v ip="10.0.4.1" -v no="20" -v line='#BalancerMember "ajp://ip:8009" route=nodeno loadfactor=1 keepalive=on ttl=300 max=400 timeout=300 retry=60' `

Comment: @Ashutosh, if you have multiple variables and some variable's values are coming in line(or you want to use them in line variable) then use inside of `awk` code like for example `print val1, val2, line`? Is that you are looking for, please do let me know.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I want to use the awk variable for example let's say `ip` inside the awk variable `line`.